# Showing next upload button after clicking on previous one

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload

I have 4 buttons which allow customer to upload photo in single product view.

I've managed to hide 3 out of 4 buttons so far. What I want to achieve is "You click one (upload a file) then another shows up etc. up until 4th - last button"

This is what i came up with, so far clicking on a button makes all buttons show up.

https://jsfiddle.net/th24Lf7d/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie').hide();
jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie').first().show();

 jQuery('.input-text.addon').on('click', function() {

     var test = jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie'); 

    jQuery(test).next().show();  

});

});
```

Comment: Share your jsfiddle

Comment: Share your full code. It looks like you are adding onClick event using class selectors, And also by selecting with class showing all the buttons.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/th24Lf7d/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `change` event instead of `click` event as follows.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie').hide();
  jQuery('.form-row.form-row-wide.addon-wrap-8-zdjecie').first().show();

  jQuery('.input-text.addon').on('change', function() {
    jQuery(this).closest("p").next().show();
  });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Legktcwg/).

Comment: Still not working as intented, I want those to pop up after next one is clicked   
        https://jsfiddle.net/th24Lf7d/

Answer (score 0):

I have created a clean implementation to help you manage this problem:

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // helpers
    var amountBtns = 4,
        currBtn = 1;

    // hide all btns and show only the first one
    $('.btn-upload').hide();
    $('.btn-upload:nth-child('+ currBtn +')').show();

    // event handler
    $('.btn-upload').on('click', function() {
        $('.btn-upload:nth-child('+ currBtn +')').hide();
        $('.btn-upload:nth-child('+ ++currBtn +')').show();                 
    });

});
```

**HTML**

```
<button class="btn-upload">btn upload 1</button>
<button class="btn-upload">btn upload 2</button>
<button class="btn-upload">btn upload 3</button>
<button class="btn-upload">btn upload 4</button>
```

It's working pretty fine.